# How to get value from specific column in 1 row using Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, generator, yield

I am learning a Python Pandas and I have a task to do a generator based on a .csv file. The generator has to be implemented as a function which is called in for loop and returnes value from the first one, second one and the last one column. To return value from function I have to use yield keyword. I wrote something like this:

```
def patient_reader(data_frame): #sa - still alive, a -age, ms - months survived
    sa = data_frame['still_alive']
    a = data_frame['age']
    ms = data_frame['months_survived']
    yield sa,a,ms
```

But  I don't know here how to implement this into a for loop. Do you have any sugestions for me?
How  could I store yielded values in the tuple or list?

Comment: See [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iloc.html). Then you only need a loop over integers for the length of the series (aka column). There is a shorter way but it needs more understanding of the Python, iterators and pandas.

Answer (score 0):

```
# try this
def patient_reader(data_frame): #sa - still alive, a -age, ms - months survived
    res_list = []
    for row in data_frame.iterrows():
        sa = row['still_alive']
        a = row['age']
        ms = row['months_survived']
        res_list.append((sa, a, ms))
    yield res_list
```

Comment: I think the generator should yield items from each row separately.